# Detect mobile device using HTTP_USER_AGENT with php

Tags: php, mobile-safari

I have issue detecting iPhone 8 on Safari on chrome is fine, I check on iPhone 10 or iPhone 11 the following code detect it correctly.

```
//_______________DETECT DEVICES__________________//
$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $tablet_browser++;
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
    $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
      $tablet_browser++;
    }
}

if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
   // do something for tablet devices
   print 'is tablet';
}
else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   // do something for mobile devices
   print 'is mobile';
}
else {
   // do something for everything else
   print 'is desktop';
}
```

The user agent variable on iPhone 8 Safari is
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15

Thank You

Comment: Is there a question there?

Comment: Nigel yes, I can't detect iPhone 8 on Safari, the above code show is desktop instead of is mobile on Safari but on Chrome is ok